# Converting List Comprehension with if all conditions to Loops in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I'm trying to convert a list comprehension I have as part of a course I'm doing to a for loop but keep bumping into errors/mistakes. I'm using an if all in the list comprehension which I can't work out what ordering/how to incorporate this into a for loop.

My code is:

```
def count_primes(num):
    prime = [x for x in range(2,num) if all (x % y != 0 for y in range (2,x))]
    return len(prime)
```

I've currently tried (but not working)

```
def count_primes(num):
    primes = [2]
    for x in range(3,num):
        for y in range(2,x):
            if x % y == 0:
                break
            else:
                primes.append(x)
                break

    return len(primes)
```

Comment: Have a look at your condition check. You aren't actually looping over y because it will break either in if or in else right away but the condition must be true for all y in the range.

Comment: Your code is not a function, why `return primes`?

Comment: @JamiuShaibu Sorry this is part of a function, I forgot to copy the code in for that

Comment: @JamiuShaibu It was part of a function but I forgot to copy that line in, updating now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
primes = [2]
for x in range(3, num):
    all_check = True
    for y in range(2, x):
        if x % y == 0:
           all_check = False
            break
    if all_check:
        primes.append(x)
```

You weren't actually looping all the way through in your example to check the value.